# Single release app con Expo y Apple ID sin paga

Tags: react-native, expo, certificado-apple

Estaba trabajando con un proyecto hecho con `reac-native init` y, con xCode y mi cuenta de desarrollador gratuita, me permitía crear una app de release para instalarla en mi iPhone, SOLAMENTE EN UN DISPOSITIVO. Para probarla libremente sin necesidad de depender del servidor cuando estaba en modo DEBUG.

Ahora, algunos componentes ya son compatibles con Expo e hice las modificaciones para que funcionara todo con Expo, y mi pregunta es ¿con Expo puedo crear la aplicación en modo release para instalarla en mi iPhone con cuenta de desarrollador gratuita? Tal como lo hacía anteriormente

Cuando intento con el comando `expo buid:ios`, me sale el siguiente error, después de poner mi Apple ID y mi contraseña

```js
Trying to authenticate with Apple Developer Portal...
Authenticated with Apple Developer Portal successfully!
Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed!
You have no team associated with your Apple account, cannot proceed.
(Do you have a paid Apple Developer account?)
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Para poder compilar una versión release en Expo para iOS, es necesario que tengas una cuenta de desarrollador activa, para poder firmar el archivo .ipa. El error que te arroja la consola, es porque no tienes activa una cuenta de desarrollador.

La única forma en la que podrías compilar una versión release para tu dispositivo seria desde Xcode poniendo la aplicación en modo Release y corriendo la aplicación en tu dispositivo.

Puedes configurar xcode en modo release en `Product → Scheme → Edit Scheme` en la tab de RUN en Build Configuration pon la opción de Release

[image: xcode schema]

Puedes consultar toda la documentación en [introducir la descripción del enlace aquí](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device)

Comment: Desde xCode solo aplicaría para proyecto hechos con react-native init, no? Mi proyecto estaba hecho antes con eso y exactamente así cómo lo dices, lo hice. Fui traspasando todo a uno con Expo y funciona bien. Mi cuenta de desarrollador de Apple está activa, de no ser así no hubiera podido hacer release con react-native init. Alguna otra idea para firmar el .ipa con mi cuenta de desarrollador free?

Comment: Tus estás trabajando todo sobre esto, tendrías que hacer un detach para poder compilar desde Xcode. El problema es que pedrerías las opciones de compilación automática con Expo . Puedes checar la documentación aquí https://docs.expo.io/versions/v28.0.0/expokit/detach/. Para compilar con Expo si necesitas haber pagado la licencia de desarrollo de apple.